# Профили ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, сессия, profile

Для чего в ASP.NET используются провайдеры профилей? Какую выгоду они имеют? И в чем различие между `HttpContext.Profile` и `Session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session`, как можно понять из названия, отвечает за текущую сессию пользователя, т.е. это его оперативные, текущие, данные.

`Profile`- это специфические данные пользователя, которые нужно хранить постоянно: аватар, настройки, предпочтения.

То есть, разница между сессиями и профилями в ASP.NET такая же, как везде, где есть эти понятия :)

Говоря о выгодах, процитирую [статью](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/security/level4/4_5.php):

> Наиболее впечатляет то, что это средство интегрировано с моделью аутентификации ASP.NET так, что информация о пользователе автоматически извлекается для текущего пользователя, когда это необходимо, и (если эта информация изменяется) записывается в базу данных в конце текущего запроса